# Using "eval" for user-supplied integration function?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand eval(), but am not having much luck.

I am writing my own math library and am trying to include integration into the library. I need help getting python to recognize the function as a series of variables, constants, and operators. I was told that eval would do the trick but how would i go about it?

```
fofx = input ("Write your function of x here >")
def integrate (fofx):
    #integration algorithm here
    #input fofx and recognize it as f(x) to be integrated.
```

i have tried the documentation but that is limited and i have no clue how i could apply it to my function to be evaluated.

Comment: `eval` will not help here. Look at [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/ast.html "Abstract Syntax Trees")

Comment: you mean that http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval is limited? What is unclear about this link?

Comment: Is this python 3 or 2.x?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for [`eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) is pretty clear in my view and gives a reasonable example of what you need.

Basically you want to hold an expression to be evaluated in a string:

```
>>> f = 'x**2 + 2*x'
```

Then you can define a value for `x`:

```
>>> x = 3
```

And finally call evaluate:

```
>>> eval(f)
15
```

Or if you want to make the call to eval a little more controlled, as opposed to creating a local variable named `x`, then you can pass in the evaluation environment in the parameters to `eval()`:

```
>>> f = 'x**2 + 2*x'
>>> eval(f, {}, {'x': 5})
35
```

The reason you want to control the evaluation environment is to avoid any variables defined in your program inadvertently being used in the evaluation.

Comment: Or to prevent some joker trying to integrate the "function of x" `import sys; sys.exit()`.

Comment: @Li-aungYip No amount of constraining the inputs to eval is going to stop abuse like that. I'm kind of assuming that this is a personal project and worries about malicious input can simply be ignored.

Comment: It's best to teach defensive programming at an early age. Today's users of `eval()` are tomorrow's users of `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE column=%s" % user_input`.

Comment: @Li-aung Yip In principle I agree. However, I think you need to learn how to use eval before you can learn how it can be abused. And there's only so much that can be done in an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you might be thinking of the 'eval' mode of the abstract syntax tree module which allows you to constuct a syntax tree for a single expression.

For example the code below will take an expression in a string and modify it such that 'x**2+3*x** 4+2' changes to 'x**3+3*x** 5+2'.  (Note that this is not the integral of the expression, that code would be much longer!)

```
import ast

class IncreasePower(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_BinOp(self,node):
        node=self.generic_visit(node)
        if isinstance( node.op , ast.Pow) and isinstance(node.right, ast.Num):
            node.right.n+=1
        return node

x=4
s='x**2+3*x**4+2'
print eval(s)

A = ast.parse(s,'source','eval')
B = IncreasePower().visit(A)
E = compile(A,'increased','eval')

print eval(E)
```

You may also find it helpful to look at the symbolic maths library sympy which uses a different approach to building up expressions.  In sympy you start with x=sympy.Symbol("x") before constructing your expressions.

The "sympy.integrate" function does symbolic integration.

Comment: Very nice answer! Makes me want to learn `ast` in detail.